# How to build SharpMap

Tags: visual-studio, sharpmap, github

I am trying to test the SharpMap 1.2 libraries. I cloned the build from https://github.com/SharpMap/SharpMap and ran a Build. I encountered 56 errors under VS2015. There is virtually no info on how to build on GitHub. Is there a step I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

After some research it appears the project requires C# 7.0. Opened the project in VS2017 and it compiles fine.

Comment: My biuld also failed but i found a dependency issue in a readme https://github.com/SharpMap/SharpMap/tree/Branches/1.0/SharpMap.SqlServerSpatialObjects